# bootstrap columns not aligned in sync

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have two columns which need to be adjacent to each other. Attached below is the image for this. Currently, they are not aligned properly.[image]

The code for this is shown below:

HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="bldgInfo">
<div class="col-md-2" id="titles">
</div>
<div class="col-md-2" id="values">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#info").tooltip();//call the tooltip function
    $("#info").click(function () {
        infoHead = "infoHead"
        type = $("#ResidentialBuildingType").val();
        stories = $("#ResidentialBuildingStories").val();
        size = $("#ResidentialBuildingSize").val();
        url = "/ResidentialBuilding/getBldgInfo?type=" + type + "&stories=" + stories + "&size=" + size;
        $('#bldgInfo').slideToggle(function () {
            console.log(url);
            $('#titles').empty();
            $("#values").empty();
            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $("#titles").append('<h5 id="' + infoHead + '">' + value.r.type +  " (" + value.r.stories + ")"  + '</h5>');
                    $("#titles").append('<p>' + "Stories" + '</p>');
                    $("#titles").append('<p>' + "Age" + '</p>');
                    $("#titles").append('<p>' + "Size" + '</p>');
                    $("#titles").append('<p>' + "Orientation" + '</p>');
                    $("#titles").append('<p>' + "Shape" + '</p>');
                    $("#titles").append('<p>' + "Floor Height" + '</p>');
                    $("#titles").append('<p>' + "Foundation" + '</p>');
                    $("#titles").append('<p>' + "Window Percent" + '</p>');
                    $("#titles").append('<p>' + "Heating" + '</p>');
                    $("#titles").append('<p>' + "Cooling" + '</p>');
                    $("#values").append('<p>' + value.r.stories + '</p>');
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

The #title column contains the SFD (1) text and the p elements below it. 
The #values should be aligned adjacent i.e. Stories should have the 1 (that is currently way off) adjacent to it. Any help? I have tried most of what I know

Comment: It looks like they are actually aligned, and the padding/margin of your h5 tag may be bumping the left column down.

Comment: The h5 element is generated on the fly since its getting information from the database. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Add padding to your `value.r.stories` p tag or stick it in an `h5`. Or get rid of the `h5` on the first column.

Comment: Tried adding padding. It does not get it done.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with the code as an example for us to play with?

Comment: Here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Lr86q/
The "1" and "2" should be adjacent to each to the first div. It's not working for some odd reason.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the button in the first one pushing the others out of alignment.
You can just make an invisible button in the second, or move the button into its own row:
I changed the `col-md` to `col-xs` so it would look right on jsfiddle where the viewport is smaller, and I changed the id to a class because I'm reusing it.

```
<div class="row" id="bldgInfo">
  <div class="col-xs-2" id="titles">
    <h5 class="infoHead">SFD (1)</h5>
    <p>Stories</p>
    <p>Age</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2" id="values">
    <h5 class="infoHead invisible">&nbsp;</h5>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yTCPX/1/

Comment: Does the class invisible just have display: none property?

Comment: No, in bootstrap it's `visibility: hidden`

Comment: Works but its not responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I see Dave's answer above, another implementation would be to put a class on your first generated p tag that bumps it down.

http://www.bootply.com/Ik1hfc9aW0

**HTML**

```
<p class="first">1</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.first{
   margin-top:56px;
}
```